# Provident Fund transfer from a company which got acquired by another company

Tags: income-tax, india, provident-fund

My husband has changed job to another company and had not transferred his PF at that time. Later the previous company he was employed in got acquired by another company. Now he has initiated PF transfer through current employer but when they sent to previous employer, they are saying its not in their account, its in the old company's account. Please suggest how can he transfer his PF in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If the account was linked to UAN, then you can transfer this online as well. The [EPFO site](https://www.epfindia.gov.in/site_en/For_Employees.php) gives the details.

If the account was not linked, if you have a previous salary slip; it would indicate the PF Account number with the old company. It would also give the details of the Office where the account is held. You can visit the office and request for transfer to the new PF account.